# Casting issues using argument input from C

Tags: c, string, command-line-arguments, compiler-warnings, strtol

I am trying to write a C program, where a user must input two arguments into the command line. First, they must provide a name of a text file of values to be read. Second, they must provide a value of 0 or 1, which will be saved as an integer to be used as a boolean (0=false, 1=true).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   FILE *f;
   char *fname;
   int boolVal;

  if (argc != 2){
    printf("This program requires two input types, data file and boolean value of 0 or 1\n");
    return 1;
  } 

  fmame = argv[1];
  boolVal = argv[2];
  printf("The file name is %s and the boolVal is %d.\n", fmame, boolVal);

   f = fopen(fname, "r");
   if (f == NULL) perror ("Could not open file");
      else {
         if (fgets(myStr, 1000, f) != NULL )
            puts(myStr);
            fclose(f);
      }
   return 0;
}
```

I get an error:

```
testArg.c: In function ‘main’:
testArg.c:16: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

I have two questions: Is my reading in of the file name correct? Second, how to solve the issue of casting?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning.

Comment: In C it's actually a warning on most compilers. It's incorrect, but it's technically possible to do at the static level @danielfranca.

Comment: @danielfranca, it's a constraint violation, a compiler must _at least_ warn, but may also refuse to compile. In other words, this warning should be treated as an error.

Comment: the program returns -1 if incorrect number of arguments (which should be 3, not 2 as the program name is argv[0])  so why is the program returning a success indication (0) when it could not open the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your requirement,

> where a user must input two arguments into the command line. First, they must provide a name of a text file of values to be read. Second, they must provide a value of 0 or 1, which will be saved as an integer to be used as a boolean (0=false, 1=true).

your code should read like

```
if (argc != 3)
{  //code
```

remember, the binary name also counts. So `./<binary> <filename> <1/0>` makes the `argc` as `3`.

Next, the reason for the warning in your code is for

```
boolVal = argv[2];
```

All the command line inputs are read in a form of string [`char *`]. You can understand that easily if you check the data type of `argv[2]`. Isn't it say `char *`? Then, you need to *convert* that *(alpha)numeric string* to an *integer* value before you assign that value to an `int` variable.

So, what you need here is

```
boolVal = atoi(argv[2]);
```

or, even better and recommended,

```
boolVal = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
```

Please check the man page of [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) for details.

Comment: Why not `if (argc > 2) { //code` to allow addition of additional command line arguments later without a rewrite of existing code?

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder if I may also ask... why does my code here print out the first line of the file into the console? Is there a way I can suppress that? I get a feeling it occurs during part of the else statement.

Comment: @JosephHudson yes, it prints that because you asked it to do so. :-) See, if the `fgets()` returns success, the `puts(string);` will be executed, printning the first line of your file. If you don't want the o/p, remove the `puts()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning one pointer that `bool` variable. You have to do like this.

```
boolVal=atoi(argv[2]);
```

Now it will not throw any warning. Then you have to check the condition that is not as `argc != 3`. Otherwise it give you a segmentation fault. Because `argc` will have the count from zero. If you are simple giving the `./a.out` then the `argc` count is one.

You are accessing like this, `argv[2]` So you have to check that `argc != 3`.

```
 int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

`atoi` will convert the array value into integer value. From the man page of `atoi`

> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int.

Refer [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

Comment: What does `atoi` do? Please include that information in your post.

Answer (score 2):

One way to compare the value of a string argument passed in `argv` to to `1` would be as follows:

```
boolVal = argv[2][0] == '1';
```

This, however, is a shortcut that works because the string is a single character long. For longer strings, use [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html):

```
boolVal = strcmp(argv[2], "yes") == 0;
```

Note: you should also check that `argc` is three because of mandatory parameter at position zero.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (argc != 2)
```

To this:

```
if (argc != 3 || (argv[2][0] != '0' && argv[2][0] != '1') || argv[2][1] != '\0')
```

And this:

```
boolVal = argv[2];
```

To this:

```
boolVal = argv[2][0]-'0';
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (argc != 2){
```

should be

```
if (argc != 3){
```

as `argv[0]` will be the name of the program that you run and you want two other inputs too. Thus, the check with `argc` should be with 3 instead of 2.

As for the warning, it is because here:

```
boolVal = argv[2];
```

`boolVal` is of type `int` while `argv[2]` is of type `char*`. You can't directly assign them and this is what the compiler is complaining about. Use

```
sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&boolVal);
```

to extract a number from `argv[2]` and store it in the address of `boolVal`. `sscanf` returns the total number of items successfully scanned and assigned. So, You can also check if the extraction was successful by using

```
if(sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&boolVal)==1)
    //Extraction successful!
```

Furthermore, you can check if the successfully extracted number is either 1 or 0 by using

```
if(boolVal !=0 && boolVal !=1)
    //Bad Value
```